# Radio button feature in uiindexed tableview in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, radio-button

I am creating an app in which user has been provided with the feature just like radio button.

I had added the button in tableview cell and its also acting like radio button but not in all cells working only in some of the cells.

Also the cells on which feature is working i have problem that it get deselected when i scroll the table view.

Please anyone help me out or provide a snippet.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: You mean only one of the row should be selected at a time ?

Answer (score 0):

When the UITableViewCell scrolls off the screen, it is actually reused by the UITableView. You will need to account for this by saving off the state of each button in your model the moment they are pressed and then during `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, read back in that value and set the button's state.